# Stocktwits API Authentication invalid/unknown client error

Tags: oauth, stocktwits

I'm using these docs to figure out how to get stocktwits oauth to work:

http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication

http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/api#oauth-authorize-docs

Yes, I have been using my consumer key in place of the client_id, in reference to this:

api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize?client_id=&response_type=token&redirect_uri=www.example.com&scope=read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,follow_users,follow_stocks

When I try to access this url in chrome, firefox, or the command line, I keep getting this error:

Error: invalid_client unknown client

Any advice? Not sure what else I need to initially specify apart from the client_id/consumer key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your client_id is not correct. You can get your client_id when you go to your registered app located in the "My Apps" section of the developer portal here:
https://stocktwits.com/developers/apps

Then click "View key & details" on your app and then your client_id should be **Consumer key** put this key in the url:

api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/authorize?client_id=**PUT CONSUMER KEY HERE**&response_type=token&redirect_uri=www.example.com&scope=read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,follow_users,follow_stocks

If you have any other issue or still get this response please email support directly at: [support@stocktwits.com](http://mailto%3asupport@stocktwits.com)